# Scala, user input till only newline is given

Tags: scala

I have tried to get multiple user inputs to print them in Scala IDE.

I have tried the this piece of code

```
println(scala.io.StdIn.readLine())
```

which works, as the IDE takes my input and then print it in the line but this works only for a single input.
I want the code to take multiple inputs till only newline is entered. example,

```
1
2
3
```

so i decided we needed an iterator for the input, which led me to try the following 2 lines of code seperately

```
var in = Iterator.continually{ scala.io.StdIn.readLine() }.takeWhile { x => x != null}
```

and

```
var in = io.Source.stdin.getLines().takeWhile { x => x != null}
```

Unfortunately none of them worked as the IDE is not taking my input at all.

Comment: Is your program going to expect/process all the lines at once, or do you you need the lazy semantics of `Iterator`?

Comment: it should expect all the lines at once. Not in a single line but on multiple lines entered from an user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're really close.

```
val in = Iterator.continually(io.StdIn.readLine).takeWhile(_.nonEmpty).toList
```

This will read input until an empty string is entered and saves the input in a `List[String]`. The reason for `toList` is because an `Iterator` element doesn't become real until `next` is called on it, so `readLine` won't be called until the next element is required. The transition to `List` creates all the elements of the `Iterator`.

**update**

As @vossad01 has pointed out, this can be made safer for unexpected input.

```
val in = Iterator.continually(io.StdIn.readLine)
                 .takeWhile(Option(_).fold(false)(_.nonEmpty))
                 .toList
```

Comment: Thanks so much. i was searching from past 1 hour regarding this. I didn't know about toList part.

Comment: Should be `.takeWhile(s => s != null && s.nonEmpty)`. Otherwise you throw a NullPointerException if you encounter the end of the stream before you encounter an empty line.

Comment: @vossad01, so far I am unable to get a null or EOL from `StdIn.readLine`. How is that done?

Comment: On Linux it's `Ctrl+D` when reading from input. I'm not sure about elsewhere.  This case can also be encountered when StdIn is piped from another command or read from a file.

Comment: @vossad01, got it. The REPL was capturing/buffering `Ctrl-D` input. Running from the shell, and input from the shell, does indeed return NPE on `Ctrl-D` input.  Updated.